# Send image source from webpage to mail sending engine in another project

Tags: asp.net, image, smtpclient

I have a little web application in ASP.NET that just sends an email, body of which based is on the filled fields on an ASPX form. I construct the body and send it to my SendMail(string body, string to) method which is in another project I have a reference to.

Here's my SendMail method:

```
      public void SendMail(string body,string to)
       {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from@mydomain.com", to);
        mail.Subject = "Test subject";
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("172.16.0.4", 25);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from", "password");
        client.Send(mail);
       }
```

Everythings works fine except for one thing. To the end of my body I add this:

```
         <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="Images/image005.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         </div>
```

When I look at the received email, the image is not visible, there's an icon instead. I know that I just send the body as a string and the SendMail method doesn't know anything about the "Images/image005.jpg". What should I do to load the image properly? The Images folder is in the root folder of the application.

Comment: You need to fully qualify the image url, try using complete http://..../image/image005,jpg

Comment: I did, as you said. I both tried the fully qualified name like http://localhost/mailsenderapp/images/image005.jpg and uploading image to internet (http://s8.postimg.org/urqqdfuld/image005.jpg) and giving the full link to the image source. Neither method worked.